# What is the difference between semantic and grammatical predicates?

Tags: semantics

I know that the main difference between semantic and grammatical predicates is that the former are related to argument(s),while the latter are related to subjects. Are there any more differences?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean by "grammatical predicates"?

Comment: Probably what one would call "Verb Phrase" in English, at least. _Predicate_ is a logical term, and that's where it's defined. But traditional grammar -- i.e, the stuff taught for the last century in Anglophone schools -- uses the terms "subject" and "predicate" in much the same way as `NP` and `VP`. In fact, McCawley explicitly says that `NP` is a category that is the syntactic equivalent of the logical category `Argument of Predicate`, so it makes sense to think of `VP` (pronounce it Vee-bar if you prefer) as the syntactic equivalent of the logical category `Predicate`.

Comment: I would guess that the difference is that the semantic predicate refers to the innate arguments of a verb, while grammatical predicates refer to the arguments that are actually present in a sentence, which will be different if it is a passive for example. But we really need more context to answer this question because the terms could be used in a variety of ways.